# Как разложишь объект в php?

Tags: php, php7

С базы данных приходит объект вот такого вида

```
$market = {"1":{"k":"2.75"},"2":{"k":"7.8"},"3":{"k":"1.73"}}
```

Подскажите, как его тремя значениями заполнить теги `html`
Надо так:

```
<span>2.75</span>
<span>7.8</span>
<span>1.73</span>
```

Пробовал получить

```
echo '
<span>'.$market["1"]["k"].'</span>
<span>'.$market["2"]["k"].'</span>
<span>'.$market["3"]["k"].'</span>
'
```

Но это не сработало.

Comment: Используйте json_decode , а далее всё получится

Comment: php не js, тут у объектов насколько мне известно нет "массивного" синтаксиса. пробуйте что то типа `$marker::3::k;` или `$marker=>3=>k;` а лучше отправляйте этот объект как есть на фронт, js его "распарсит" автоматически и спокойно предоставит хоть массивным синтаксисом хоть объектным. ну или как посоветовали выше json_decode...

Comment: Сначала `json_decode`, потом можете сдлать так `$data->{1}->k`

Answer (score 0):

Да, спасибо @Виктор
Ответ

```
$market1 = json_decode($item->market1, true);
      <span>' . $market1["1"]["k"] . '</span>
      <span>' . $market1["2"]["k"] . '</span>
      <span>' . $market1["3"]["k"] . '</span>
```